# predict() and newdata - How does this work?

Tags: r, regression, lm, predict

Someone recently posted a question on this paper here: https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//googleblogs/pdfs/google_predicting_the_present.pdf

The R code of the paper can be found at the very end of the paper. Essentially, the paper investigates one-month ahead predictions of sales through search queries. I think I understood the model and method, but there's one detail that puzzles me. It's the part:

```
1 ##### Divide data by two parts - model fitting & prediction
dat1 = mdat[1:(nrow(mdat)-1), ]
dat2 = mdat[nrow(mdat), ]

2 ##### Fit Model;
fit = lm(log(sales) ~ log(s1) + log(s12) + trends1, data=dat1);
summary(fit)
```

and:

```
3 #### Prediction for the next month;
predict.fit = predict(fit, newdata=dat2, se.fit=TRUE);
```

I do understand, that `dat2` in (1) is only the last row from `mdat`. (2) means that the regression model is applied to everything but the last row in the dataset.

But why is `newdata=dat2` in the prediction model of (3) being used and what does it mean? Why the last row only?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a description for each line of the code:

```
dat1 = mdat[1:(nrow(mdat)-1), ]
```

Creates a subset of the whole dataset which contains all but the last row.

```
dat2 = mdat[nrow(mdat), ]
```

Creates a subset of the whole dataset which contains only the last row.

```
fit = lm(log(sales) ~ log(s1) + log(s12) + trends1, data=dat1)
```

For the model fitting is only the first subset `dat1` used. So the data without the last row.

```
predict.fit = predict(fit, newdata=dat2, se.fit=TRUE)
```

`predict` takes the fitted model and looks what it would predict for the "unseen" data `dat2`.

In the easiest case with only one independent variable we would fit a line to `dat1` and then look which Y-value would be predicted for the X-value of `dat2`.

Comment: But then why is only one value being used? One value in the future? Because the paper only concentrates on the one-month prediction? Assuming it would look at 3-m predictions, then would dat2 be the last three values?

Comment: Right. You could easily use more than one value then you would work with `dat1 <- mdat[1:(nrow(mdat)-3), ]` and `dat2 = mdat[(nrow(mdat) - 2) : nrow(mdat), ]`. However, if it was their aim only to predict one month ahead and not three (which might be reasonable because you loose accuracy if you look farther in the future) why should they waste 2 additional observations which are most probably the most important because they are the most current?

Comment: Okay, so the MAE in the paper is then measured with the running values from the regression on dat1 (i.e. `predict.fit = predict(fit, se.fit=TRUE)`), right? Because `predict.fit = predict(fit, newdata=dat2, se.fit=TRUE)` only returns one value. I still wonder when and where this result from `predict.fit = predict(fit, newdata=dat2, se.fit=TRUE)` is being used.

Comment: As I understand it they fitted the model to `dat1` at time t and predicted for t+1. Then they added the true outcome in t + 1 and added it to dat1. With this dat1 in t+1 they predicted the value in t+2 and so on (rolling regression).  However, I cannot say that I found the code for this in the paper.

Comment: Yes, I think when creating the MAE measure, you need to create a df with each the actual values and regression results for each lag of Google Trends. I am just not sure if the value from `predict.fit = predict(fit, newdata=dat2, se.fit=TRUE)` is being used anywhere, that's why I asked. For now, I'd just take `predict.fit = predict(fit, se.fit=TRUE)` and compare the regression results with the actual results.

Comment: So my idea is to create an MAE by taking the results from `predict.fit = predict(fit, se.fit=TRUE)` for t+1 and simply comparing them with the actual values of t+1. The differences here then would be the absolute error. The result from `predict.fit = predict(fit, newdata=dat2, se.fit=TRUE)` would remain unused?

Comment: The paper says: _"Does the Google Trends data help with prediction? To answer this question we make a series of one-month ahead predictions and compute the prediction error defined in Equation 1.5. The average of the absolute values of the prediction errors is known as the mean absolute error (MAE). Each forecast uses only the information available up to the time the forecast is made, which is one week into the month in question."_