# Rolling regression and prediction with lm() and predict()

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, predict

I need to apply `lm()` to an enlarging subset of my dataframe `dat`, while making prediction for the next observation. For example, I am doing:

```
fit model      predict
----------     -------
dat[1:3, ]     dat[4, ]
dat[1:4, ]     dat[5, ]
    .             .
    .             .
dat[-1, ]      dat[nrow(dat), ]
```

I know what I should do for a particular subset (related to this question: [predict() and newdata - How does this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38036874/4891738)). For example to predict the last row, I do

```
dat1 = dat[1:(nrow(dat)-1), ]
dat2 = dat[nrow(dat), ]

fit = lm(log(clicks) ~ log(v1) + log(v12), data=dat1)
predict.fit = predict(fit, newdata=dat2, se.fit=TRUE)
```

How can I do this automatically for all subsets, and potentially extract what I want into a table?

- From `fit`, I'd need the `summary(fit)$adj.r.squared`;
- From `predict.fit` I'd need `predict.fit$fit` value.

Thanks.

Comment: I added an example of how to create a table of results from the output, please check it out. I only did it for the 1 of the 3 types of output objects my solution produces, but the same methodology works for all 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**(Efficient) solution**

This is what you can do:

```
p <- 3  ## number of parameters in lm()
n <- nrow(dat) - 1

## a function to return what you desire for subset dat[1:x, ]
bundle <- function(x) {
  fit <- lm(log(clicks) ~ log(v1) + log(v12), data = dat, subset = 1:x, model = FALSE)
  pred <- predict(fit, newdata = dat[x+1, ], se.fit = TRUE)
  c(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared, pred$fit, pred$se.fit)
  }

## rolling regression / prediction
result <- t(sapply(p:n, bundle))
colnames(result) <- c("adj.r2", "prediction", "se")
```

Note I have done several things inside the `bundle` function:

- I have used `subset` argument for selecting a subset to fit
- I have used `model = FALSE` to not save model frame hence we save workspace

Overall, there is no obvious loop, but `sapply` is used.

- Fitting starts from `p`, the minimum number of data required to fit a model with `p` coefficients;
- Fitting terminates at `nrow(dat) - 1`, as we at least need the final column for prediction.

---

**Test**

Example data (with 30 "observations")

```
dat <- data.frame(clicks = runif(30, 1, 100), v1 = runif(30, 1, 100),
                  v12 = runif(30, 1, 100))
```

Applying code above gives `results` (27 rows in total, truncated output for 5 rows)

```
            adj.r2 prediction        se
 [1,]          NaN   3.881068       NaN
 [2,]  0.106592619   3.676821 0.7517040
 [3,]  0.545993989   3.892931 0.2758347
 [4,]  0.622612495   3.766101 0.1508270
 [5,]  0.180462206   3.996344 0.2059014
```

The first column is the adjusted-R.squared value for fitted model, while the second column is the prediction. The first value for `adj.r2` is `NaN`, because the first model we fit has 3 coefficients for 3 data points, hence no sensible statistics is available. The same happens to `se` as well, as the fitted line has no 0 residuals, so prediction is done without uncertainty.

Comment: Possible that you could answer me one last question?

Answer (score 1):

I just made up some random data to use for this example. I'm calling the object `data` because that was what it was called in the question at the time that I wrote this solution (call it anything you like).

**(Efficient) Solution**

```
data <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(100),v2=rnorm(100),clicks=rnorm(100))

data1 = data[1:(nrow(data)-1), ]
data2 = data[nrow(data), ]

for(i in 3:nrow(data)){
  nam  <- paste("predict", i, sep = "")
  nam1 <- paste("fit", i, sep = "")
  nam2 <- paste("summary_fit", i, sep = "")

  fit = lm(clicks ~ v1 + v2, data=data[1:i,])
  tmp  <- predict(fit, newdata=data2, se.fit=TRUE)
  tmp1 <- fit
  tmp2 <- summary(fit)
  assign(nam, tmp)
  assign(nam1, tmp1)
  assign(nam2, tmp2)
}
```

All of the results you want will be stored in the data objects this creates.

**For example:**

```
> summary_fit10$r.squared
[1] 0.3087432
```

You mentioned in the comments that you'd like a **table of results**. You can programmatically create tables of results from the 3 types of output files like this:

```
rm(data,data1,data2,i,nam,nam1,nam2,fit,tmp,tmp1,tmp2)
frames <- ls()

frames.fit     <- frames[1:98] #change index or use pattern matching as needed
frames.predict <- frames[99:196]
frames.sum     <- frames[197:294]

fit.table <- data.frame(intercept=NA,v1=NA,v2=NA,sourcedf=NA)
for(i in 1:length(frames.fit)){
  tmp <- get(frames.fit[i])
  fit.table              <- rbind(fit.table,c(tmp$coefficients[[1]],tmp$coefficients[[2]],tmp$coefficients[[3]],frames.fit[i]))
}

fit.table

> fit.table
             intercept                   v1                   v2 sourcedf
2  -0.0647017971121678     1.34929652763687   -0.300502017324518    fit10
3  -0.0401617893034109   -0.034750571912636  -0.0843076273486442   fit100
4   0.0132968863522573     1.31283604433593   -0.388846211083564    fit11
5   0.0315113918953643     1.31099122173898   -0.371130010135382    fit12
6    0.149582794027583    0.958692838785998   -0.299479715938493    fit13
7  0.00759688947362175    0.703525856001948   -0.297223988673322    fit14
8    0.219756240025917    0.631961979610744   -0.347851129205841    fit15
9     0.13389223748979    0.560583832333355   -0.276076134872669    fit16
10   0.147258022154645    0.581865844000838   -0.278212722024832    fit17
11  0.0592160359650468    0.469842498721747   -0.163187274356457    fit18
12   0.120640756525163    0.430051839741539   -0.201725012088506    fit19
13   0.101443924785995     0.34966728554219   -0.231560038360121    fit20
14  0.0416637001406594    0.472156988919337   -0.247684504074867    fit21
15 -0.0158319749710781    0.451944113682333   -0.171367482879835    fit22
16 -0.0337969739950376    0.423851304105399   -0.157905431162024    fit23
17  -0.109460218252207     0.32206642419212   -0.055331391802687    fit24
18  -0.100560410735971    0.335862465403716  -0.0609509815266072    fit25
19  -0.138175283219818    0.390418411384468  -0.0873106257144312    fit26
20  -0.106984355317733    0.391270279253722  -0.0560299858019556    fit27
21 -0.0740684978271464    0.385267011513678  -0.0548056844433894    fit28
```

Comment: Looks good so far, but how can I see the values or a table of the predictions? Doing some research, *rollapply* might also be an option but I'm unfortunately too novice to deal with it.

Comment: @JohnnyDeer Yea there are some rolling regression functions you could use but you don't really need them for this. The results you want are in the data sets this produces and you can see them with `str(predict3)` or by accessing the whole object or elements of it. If you would like a table of results that's no problem but please open a separate question for it. Using `str` will describe the structure so that you know how to access the elements you want programmatically.

Comment: @JohnnyDeer I'm also about to make an update actually to provide more information in the output datasets. Have a look now.

Comment: @JohnnyDeer updated again to give you the table of results example