# Rolling regression and prediction by date with lm() and predict()

Tags: r, loops, regression, lm, predict

So I am doing a rolling regression with lm() and predict() based on the following question + top answer and it worked perfectly with my data

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38041406/9932223

My issue is that I don't want a new lm() fit after each row. My data has multiple rows for each date, and not always the same number of rows for each date. If I want to have a new lm() fit at the end of each date's set of rows (and continue to use all previous data from all dates prior) how would I modify this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider calling the method inside an `lapply` call to iterate through unique values of dates used for data frame filtering in `lm` calls:

```
# ORDER BY DATE ASC
dat <- with(dat, dat[order(Date),])

bundle <- function(curr_date) {
  # REPLACING subset WITH FILTER FOR ALL DATES BEFORE CURRENT DATE
  fit <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = dat[dat$Date < curr_date,], model = FALSE)

  # REPLACE FILTER FOR ALL DATES ON CURRENT DATE
  pred <- predict(fit, newdata = dat[dat$Date == curr_date,], se.fit = TRUE)

  # RETURN DATA FRAME OF RESULTS
  data.frame(date = curr_date,
             adj_r = summary(fit)$adj.r.squared, 
             fit = pred$fit, 
             se_fit = pred$se.fit)
}

# LAPPLY CALL 
rolling_models_df_list <- lapply(unique(dat$Date)[-1], bundle)
```

Comment: I think we're getting closer but the result is only giving me the adjusted R2 value for each unique data, but not the predicted value of each row based on the lm() using the data up to and including the previous date, any suggestion on how to rectify this?

Comment: See update. I forgot to filter inside the `predict()` call, only did so in `lm`.

Comment: I'm getting an error now after the rolling_models line

Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases

Comment: Of course! The first unique date would not have any records before it. I adjusted the `unique` call to leave that one out.

Comment: Awesome! It worked! The one last thing I'm looking for is the data to get cleaned up, I need it to come out in those three columns, adjusted R2, Prediction and SE but right now it's sort of a matrix for each unique date. Just looking for those columns and the same number of rows as I have for the data, any work around for this?

Comment: See update with function now returning a data frame of four columns where you now build a list of dfs.

Comment: Haha! Great to hear. Glad to help.